# Dados de uma requisição POST pelo PHP não chegam como JSON

Tags: php, post, libcurl

Estou com um problema para fazer uma requisição POST direto do PHP para o REST, pois os dados não chegam em formato JSON.

> {"status":"ok","result":{ "user"{"id":"xxx","username":"xxx","email":"xxx","limit_of_sessions":1,"strategy_of_sessions":"xxx","type":"xxx"},"token":"xxxx"}
>   }

Porém quando vou pegar o valor do objeto ele retorna o valor 1 ou true.

```
<?php

$url = url;

$fields = array("login"=>"xxx","password"=>"xxx");
$fields = json_encode($fields);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' 
  ));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r( "Resultado ".$result[0]['status']);

curl_close($ch);
```

Já tentei usar o JSON_encode() ou JSON_decode() e nada.

Comment: me parece que você está convertendo em json só o $fields quando na verdade deveria converter o resultado

Comment: Isso mesmo, Marcos. Utilizei     $formatedResponse = '['.$result.']'; e foi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Feito, Obrigado!

Comment: valeu, por nada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está convertendo em json só o $fields quando na verdade deveria converter o resultado